# TripTog's problem with his socks

Tags: mathematics, no-computers, combinatorics

Our friendly three-footed alien TripTog has two triplets of socks, which he keeps in a drawer in a room.

Each triplet of socks is labeled 1, 2 or 3, because TripTog is **very** meticulous about which sock goes on which foot!

Every morning when TripTog wants to put his socks on, he goes into his sock room, and pulls out a sock one at a time. If he doesn't pull out his socks in the correct order, he goes barefoot for the day.

> **How many days on average does TripTog walk around barefooted?**

Comment: Despite the nice story, this seems to be a standard mathematical probability question, without any real puzzle element, so I voted to close. Am I missing something?

Comment: I get the answer as $\binom63 5^2$ over $720$, and I was hoping someone could validate, but it probably is merely a maths question at the end of the day.

Answer (score 4):

> For the first sock TripTog has a 2/6 = 1/3 chance to pull out a correct sock.
>  For the second one he has a 2/5 chance.
>  For the third one he has a 2/4 = 1/2 chance.
>
>  1/3 * 2/5 * 1/2 = 1/15
>  On every 15th day, TripTog pulls out the socks in the correct order.
>  So on average on 14 out of 15 days he walks around barefooted.
>
>  Poor TripTog ༼ つ ◕_◕ ༽つ